# stm32mp1 openSTLinux display driver customization errors

Tags: linux, stm32, yocto

I'm working on a stm32mp1 OpenSTLinux Yocto project. I need to customize the linux display driver (1024x600 RGB 24bit parallel).

I created the following *panel-simple.c* patch

```
diff --git a/drivers/gpu/drm/panel/panel-simple.c b/drivers/gpu/drm/panel/panel-simple.c
index 654fea2..8e4234f 100644
--- a/drivers/gpu/drm/panel/panel-simple.c
+++ b/drivers/gpu/drm/panel/panel-simple.c
@@ -1439,6 +1439,31 @@ static const struct panel_desc innolux_zj070na_01p = {
    },
 };
 
+static const struct drm_display_mode jenson_1024x600jt60396_01_mode = {
+   .clock = 51200,
+   .hdisplay = 1024,
+   .hsync_start = 1024 + 0,
+   .hsync_end = 1024 + 0 + 320,
+   .htotal = 1024 + 0 + 320 + 0,
+   .vdisplay = 600,
+   .vsync_start = 600 + 0,
+   .vsync_end = 600 + 0 + 35,
+   .vtotal = 600 + 0 + 35 + 0,
+   .vrefresh = 60,
+   .flags = DRM_MODE_FLAG_NHSYNC | DRM_MODE_FLAG_NVSYNC,
+};
+
+static const struct panel_desc jenson_1024x600jt60396_01 = {
+   .modes = &jenson_1024x600jt60396_01_mode,
+   .num_modes = 1,
+   .bpc = 8,
+   .size = {
+       .width = 154,
+       .height = 85,
+   },
+   .bus_format = MEDIA_BUS_FMT_RGB888_1X24,
+};
+
 static const struct display_timing koe_tx31d200vm0baa_timing = {
    .pixelclock = { 39600000, 43200000, 48000000 },
    .hactive = { 1280, 1280, 1280 },
@@ -2480,6 +2505,9 @@ static const struct of_device_id platform_of_match[] = {
        .compatible = "innolux,zj070na-01p",
        .data = &innolux_zj070na_01p,
    }, {
+       .compatible = "jenson,jt60396-01",
+       .data = &jenson_1024x600jt60396_01,
+   }, {
        .compatible = "koe,tx31d200vm0baa",
        .data = &koe_tx31d200vm0baa,
    }, {
```

then, in my own devicetree patch I added the following code

```
+  panel_rgb: panel-rgb {
+                compatible = "jenson,jt60396-01";
+       status = "okay";
+       power-supply = <&lcd_3v3>;
+       backlight = <&panel_backlight>;
+       bits-per-pixel = <24>;
+       bus-width = <24>;
+       data-shift = <0>;   
+
+
+       port {
+           panel_in_rgb: endpoint {
+               remote-endpoint = <&ltdc_out_rgb>;
+           };
+       };
+  };
```

the build process ends correctly but in the boot phase the log shows the following errors

```
[11066.089809] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies] *ERROR* [CRTC:32:crtc-0] flip_done timed out
[11076.329852] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies] *ERROR* [CONNECTOR:29:DPI-1] flip_done timed out
[11086.569810] [drm:drm_atomic_helper_wait_for_dependencies] *ERROR* [PLANE:30:plane-0] flip_done timed out
```

and the display screen doesn't show anything.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: How did you get this clock value? This seems to give around a 20ns cycle time, if I'm calculating it right

Comment: the "clock" value of the "drm_display_mode" structure has to be in kHz, in my case 51200 kHz (htotal * vtotal * vrefresh = 1344*635*60 = 51206400 Hz)

Comment: Do these errors come before, after, or during probing?

Comment: The errors come during the kernel boot

Comment: I mean during boot, the `panel_simple_platform_probe` function is called to see if the hw is present, and works with the driver. Is it executed successfully?

Comment: Sorry but I'm not a Linux expert, I don't know how to answer you. One thing I can tell you is that those errors appear several times starting from power-on until the final prompt.

Comment: The first thing you want to do is to probe your driver (and hw) successfully. In its simplest form debugging starts with adding lots of printk statements to the probing subroutine, to see if everything is going alright (and to see if it is executed at all). If it fails anywhere (or it isn't even executed), then there is a starting point. If it succeeds, then at least the very basics are OK.